# How to make DropdownButtonFormField to occupy the minimum possible space?

Tags: user-interface, dart, flutter

The flutter `DropDownButton` will automatically shrink to size of the largest label of the choices, like so :-

[image]

But a `DropDownButtonFormField` changes this behavior, and instead occupies the whole space available to it.

[image]

So, how do I make the `DropDownButtonFormField` mimic the space occupation behavior of a `DropDownButton` ?

Comment: It seems that **InputDecorator** widget which wraps the DropDownButton is the cause of this behavior.

So a simple ( and probably not so correct) solution is creating your own copy of the DropdownButtonFormField ( inputdecorator should be removed)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem trying to make `DropDownButtonFormField` fit a minimal possible space in a `Row`. Unfortunately, `InputDecorator` widgets that are used inside the `DropDownButtonFormField` don't support children that can set their own width (such as `DropDownButton`) and require `maxWidth` to be capped by parent.

I managed to make it work using [IntrinsicWidth](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html) widget (warning: according to the docs, this widget is relatively expensive because it adds a speculative layout pass before the final layout phase):

```dart
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
  children: [
    IntrinsicWidth(
        child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
          value: "1",
          items: [
            DropdownMenuItem(
              value: "1",
              child: Text("1"),
            ),
            DropdownMenuItem(
              value: "2",
              child: Text("2"),
            ),
          ],
          onChanged: _onCurrencyChanged,
        )),
  ],
)
```

`IntrinsicWidth` sets child's width to the child's maximum intrinsic width, satisfying `InputDecorator`'s need to have a fixed width.